# In Marked for Death Grim Reaper

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Do all enemies in 20 yards got hit by extra 15% or is the 15% damage divided among them.

Say there are 20 enemies within 20 yards. Do all of them get 15% damage or do all of them get 15/20% damage?

> 15% of damage dealt to the marked enemy is also divided evenly among
>   all enemies within 20 yards.

I sort of guess that each other enemy got a mere 1% extra. Yet this is an extremely popular rune.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in exactly what you posted there:

> 15% of damage dealt to the marked enemy is also **divided evenly** among all enemies within 20 yards.

Emphasis mine.  That means each enemy reduces the amount of damage the others take. If there are 15, each one takes 1%.

Comment: That's pretty small. So why is it popular?